# How to add parameters in jenkins multibranche pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

Jenkins multibranch can't add parameters, this options can't click:
[image]

This page is project's develop branch.

Comment: you will need to use parameters in Jenkinfile , you can not add it from UI

Comment: thank you,I want to publish different branches to different servers,What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins multibranche pipeline you can use parameters tag.

For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        jdk 'Java11 AdoptOpenJDK'
    }

    parameters {

        string(defaultValue: "dev", description: 'set env example: dev,uat', name: 'env')
  
    }

  stages {

    stage('Testing') {

            steps {
                sh './mvnw -Denv=${env} test'
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you,I want to publish different branches to different servers,What should I do.can i add some script in anget stage?

Comment: @deqangyu i think you can write git command  as sh script for that